# django dynamic template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I try to build a plugins based application, I have created tags and registered them for each plugin.

I have a table stores each page plugins, and need to render any stored plugin in the template accordingly as inclusion tag.

Now for the template i use this:

```
{% block slider_region %}
{% for pagecontent in pagecontents %}
    {% pagecontent.plugin %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But this returns:

```
Invalid block tag: 'pagecontent.plugin', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'
```

My question, how can I pass the plugin as a tag from view query to a template and be rendered as inclusion tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the content of pagecontent.plugin. Then instead of

```
{% pagecontent.plugin %}
```

try

```
{{pagecontent.plugin}}
```